# how does paypal keep their database secure?

Tags: paypal

first off, I am not trying to hack paypal.  What I'm trying to do is to create a similarly safe database.

OK, so if i sign up with paypal, i can 'deposit' money into my paypal account from my credit card or from my bank account if i have that set up.  When this happens money is transfered from myself to paypal.  But not really into my paypal account.  That is my pay pal account is not an actual physical space with gold sitting in it.  Unless I am wrong, what happens here is my account is in a databse table on paypal's servers, and when I make a deposit, they simply change the 'balance field' from whatever to += my deposit.  So, if anyone were to be able to hack into this db, they could increase their balance by anything they wanted simply by changing the value in the 'balance field.'

How does paypal go about making sure this cant happen, and what kind of db system do you tink they use.  I would guess NOT MySQL, correct?

Thanks all.

Comment: Who says they do :) They just have good insurance (I hope)

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to be handling any customer financial data (i.e., processing credit and/or debit card transactions), you are required to be PCI compliant. This is a set of security standards setup by American Express, Discover, JCB, MasterCard, and Visa International that imposes heavy fines ($5,000 to $100,000 per month) if you are either audited or have a security breach and are found to not meet the standards. For PCI compliance, you are also required to have a network security scan performed every 90 days which "must be conducted by a PCI SSC Approved Scanning Vendor."

Although PCI compliance isn't a guarantee that you're safe (it does more to verify security at the network level, not the application level), it's at least the very least the minimum starting point. In addition, your application should be designed with security in mind to protect from SQL injection, session hi-jacking, and other common security issues.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it's MySQL -- not because of any security reasons, it's just unusual for something like MySQL to be used in a large-scale multi-national financial system.

I don't know PayPal specifically, but if I were making such a system, there would have to be an audit trail. Meaning you don't just have `"myAccount.balance = 100000000"` somewhere; you have a table of transactions, that say on date X you got a (deposit || debit) from/to (account) in the amount of Y. It adds them up and that's your balance. If there's ever a discrepency, they have that audit trail to look at and find any fraudulent or invalid transfers and correct it quickly. If there is a database field with your balance in it, it's only cached their for speed; the "real" balance comes from that audit trail.

It's the same way you balance your checkbook: you keep track of the incoming and outgoing funds, and total it up to see how much you have; if the total is wrong, you go back and look at your log of incoming and outgoing funds to find the error.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. Problem is, if they can gain access to the database, then they can generate a fake paper trail too, right?

Comment: But PayPal doesn't exist in a vacuum; you can generate a fake paper trail on PayPal's end, but when they go to match it up with other banks, they'll find the false data. For example, if somebody put in a fake deposit of $100 from Bank of America account 12345, they could go to BofA to verify if that transaction ever really happened. At some point, BofA has to give $100 to PayPal if the transaction is real; if PayPal didn't receive it, they know something is up.

Answer (score 1):

They write extremely safe code, don't ever open themselves up to SQL injection attacks, and don't have their database server sitting on the internet.  They have a dedicated QA team that tests the heck out of anything new and perform umpteen regression tests and general test scripts.

They probably hire a hacker or two to try to break the system - but only need to pay them if they fail.  :-)

Either that, or they get hacked, then sued, then go bankrupt.

Comment: well since I wont be running my own server and already have all my code written for MySQL, what about the idea of having a seperate MySQL user for each table, and only one for each table.  That way I could basically make the transaction table adrian was talking about four our five times and check each one of them before I move any 'money' around.  That way a hacker would have to get the user login/pass for all four tables before they could really hack it.  Does that make sense?  Would that work?

Comment: I don't know that several logins gives you anything.  You could instead use just one login with a really complex password (e.g. 30 random alphanumeric characters).  If a hacker can get their hands on this, then they've presumably either gotten hold of your code in which it's used, or have pulled it from the MySQL login data - in which case they'd have the other passwords anyway.

Comment: hmmm, not sure if you understand exactly what i meant.  I dont mean creating 4 logins that can access everything, i mean one login for transTbl_1 (this login is setup in MySQL to be THE ONLY user that can access trasnTbl_1, and cant access any other table). then setup another one for transTbl_2, transTbl_3, etc.  And eliminating any super user that has access to more than one table, like admin, for example.  Then the hacker would have to access all four tables and add records to all four tables before they can change how much money they have in their account.

Comment: How would a hacker get access to any one of these logins?  If access to a single login has been achieved, how difficult would you imagine it would then be to get access to the others?  Given this, do multiple logins give you much more security than one login?

Comment: well, it would be 4 times harder. lol, sorry not trying to be cute.  I would imagine they would use brute force?

Comment: Could be brute force, could be that the hacker exploits a flaw in your sites code that enables them to view the source code, etc.  Supposing that it's brute force, once login that has a complex password vs. four logins that have somewhat less complex passwords is more secure.

Comment: hmmm, good point.  could you describe briefly, or post a link to a good site that explains what kind of exploits would allow them to view my source code?

Comment: There's a plethora of exploits here - http://www.exploit-db.com/ - but that might be too hard core to start out with!  Try Googling - you'll find plenty of articles / posts.